# Cannot send string to remove licenses for user with the Set-MsolUserLicense command

Tags: c#, azure-powershell

I am trying to use `Set-MsolUserLicense` Msol Powershell command in c# to remove licenses from a user with the string

```
string removeLicense = "Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName " + "\"" 
+  selectedUPN + "\"" + " -RemoveLicenses " + accountSkuId + ":ENTERPRISEPACK";
```

where selectedUPN is the selected option obtained from a textbox.

Somehow it does not accept a string but if I type the UPN literally in the removelicense string it works.

Comment: What i mean is that if I remove the string selectedUPN from the above and add a UPN manually in the string removeLicense to process the command, it works.

Comment: Do you get any messages returned?

Comment: Maybe you don't need the quotation marks to wrap selectedUPN

Comment: The [examples in the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771770.aspx) shows you should put quotes in around both parameter values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Managed to get this sorted...created string as follows and it worked:

string removeLicense = "Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName \"" + selectedUPN + "\" -RemoveLicenses " + accountSkuId + ":ENTERPRISEPACK";